# How do I setup a CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback in SWIFT (not Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, cgpdf

I am trying to parse PDF files and I've nearly got the code working. The only thing I can't seem to figure out is to translate the following Objective C code, into Swift. I need to call my own written function to register it as a callback.

The Objective-C code is:

```
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "q", &op_q);
```

and the function is

```
static void op_q(CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    // Do whatever you have to do in here
    // info is whatever you passed to CGPDFScannerCreate
}
```

What would the Swift equivalents be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create your own `op_q` function to use as a function pointer if you don't want to.  Use Swift's closure syntax:

```
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, ("q" as NSString).UTF8String) { (s, info) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

Here `("q" as NSString).UTF8String` gives you an `UsafePointer<Int8>` which acts as a `const char *` bridged to Swift from C.

If you wanted to use a function pointer, it might look like this:

```
func op_q(s: CGPDFScannerRef, _ info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this is not working.

Comment: @cenkebret Can you elaborate a little more on what isn't working?  Is the callback not even entering the closure?  Maybe ask a new question and link back here to provide context.

Comment: it is entering, but info param is always nil

Comment: @cenkebret which syntax are you using?  The Swift closure or the function pointer?  Can you ask a new question and post your full code?

Comment: i have posted the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358521/cgpdfoperatorcallback-pdf-parser-issue-on-swift